# Enter key doesn't submit the form

Tags: jquery, dom-events, form-submit

Can you look at http://agentnet.propertyguru.com.sg/ when I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the form does not submit and I cannot find what is preventing it from happening.

You can find all the Javascript files from the source.

```
     <form action="destination" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <p class="instructions">Please enter your login id and password</p>
        <br />
        <label for="userid">User id:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" value="{$process->data.userid}" class="inputfield">
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" maxlength="32" name="password" class="inputfield">
        <br />

        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>

     </form>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is obfuscated. It's complicated to find out what's wrong.

Comment: this is not a spam, just give me some clues then

Comment: Here's a clue... write a better question please.  See http://sscce.org

Comment: I already know the answer to the better questions :P this is for someone who can have a look at the js code attached in that page

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using a `<button>` rather than an `<input type="submit">`. You can fix this by adding:

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none" />
```

Somewhere inside the form. This will "trick" the browser and re-enable Enter as a shortcut.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. I inserted the button into your DOM, and the form submitted perfectly with the Enter key.

Comment: i don't think it has anything to do with that, I have added similar code which also doesnt work in the same environment

Comment: I already added <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Login" />